# Combine several row variables

Tags: r

Given data that looks like this:

```
Year<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
Tax<-c('A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D')
Count<-c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1)
Dummy<-data.frame(Year,Tax,Count)

 Dummy
  Year  Tax Count
1   1   A     1
2   1   B     2
3   1   C     1
4   1   D     2
5   2   A     1
6   2   B     2
7   2   C     1
8   2   D     1
9   3   A     1
10  3   B     2
11  3   C     1
12  3   D     1
```

How would I go about combining some of the "Tax" elements- for instance if I wanted to combine A,B,C into a new variable "ABC". My end result should look like this

```
Year Tax Count
  1   ABC  4
  1    D   2
  2   ABC  4
  2    D   1
  3   ABC  4
  3    D   1
```

Comment: ABC is called a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another `plyr` solution. Just redefine your `Tax` variable and do a normal summary.

```
ddply(within(Dummy, {
    Tax <- ifelse(Tax %in% c('A','B','C'), 'ABC', 'D')
}), .(Year, Tax), summarise, Count=sum(Count))
```

If you don't have `plyr` (or don't like it (!)), this problem is simple enough to handle in base R in a straightforward way.

```
aggregate(Count ~ Year + Tax, within(Dummy, {
    Tax <- ifelse(Tax %in% c('A','B','C'), 'ABC', 'D')
}), sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here an option using `ddply`

```
ddply(Dummy,.(Year),summarise,
           Tax=c(Reduce(paste0,head(Tax,-1)),as.character(tail(Tax,1))),
           Count=c(sum(head(Count,-1)),tail(Count,1)))

 Year Tax Count
1    1 ABC     4
2    1   D     2
3    2 ABC     4
4    2   D     1
5    3 ABC     4
6    3   D     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here is a much better solution than my original one. No empty dataframes, no `rbind`ing, but it can still deal with arbitrary groups:

```
groups_list = list(c("A", "B", "C"), "D")
Dummy$TaxGroup = sapply(Dummy$Tax, function(tax_value) {
  group_search = sapply(groups_list, function(group) tax_value %in% group)
  group_num = which(group_search)
})
combined = ddply(
  Dummy,
  .(Year, TaxGroup),
  summarize,
  GroupName=paste(groups_list[[TaxGroup[1]]], sep="", collapse=""),
  CombinedCount=sum(Count)
)
```