# Aggregating Categorical Variable Values in a single variable in R

Tags: r, plyr, summarization

I have a dataset with the following variables - Bill_Number,Item_Name,Quantity. A single Bill_Number can have multiple Item_Names under it. I am trying to summarize it by Bill_Number and Quantity wherein the Item_Names are concatenated  into a single variable for each bill number. The solutions here :[Combine several row variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666203/combine-several-row-variables) work well for a limited and pre-defined frame (like given below), but I have hundreds of Item_Names. I am sure there is a simpler way to do this. Can anyone help please?

Data (sample only):

```
BillN<-c('B1','B1','B1','B1','B2','B2','B2','B2','B3','B3','B3','B3')

Item_Name<-c('Prod A','Prod B','Prod C','Prod D','Prod A','Prod B','Prod C','Prod D','Prod A','Prod B','Prod C','Prod D') # going on to Product(n)

Quantity<-c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1)
```

Output: using `ply::ddply`

```
ddply(within(Dummy1, {
  Item_Name <- ifelse(Item_Name %in% c('Prod A','Prod B','Prod C'), 'Prod A + Prod B + Prod C', 'Prod D')
}), .(BillN, Item_Name), summarise, Count=sum(Quantity))
```

This depends on 'Prod D' being a separate row, whereas I need a combination of all the products for a given number and the overall quantity for that bill number.

The output I require is in this format:

BillN  |  Item_Name     |            Quantity

B1   |   Prod A + Prod B + Prod C + Prod D  |   4

B2   |   Prod A + Prod B + Prod C + Prod D  |   4

B3   |   Prod A + Prod B + Prod C + Prod D  |   4

Whereas the output I get from the code above is:

BillN  |  Item_Name     |            Quantity

B1   |   Prod A + Prod B + Prod C           |   4

B1   |   Prod D                             |   2

B2   |   Prod A + Prod B + Prod C           |   4

B2   |   Prod D                             |   2

B3   |   Prod A + Prod B + Prod C           |   4

B3   |   Prod D                             |   2

Extending the scenario, what happens if I have more variables such as the Brand, Category, Sub_category for each Item_Name and the Sales_Amount as a numeric variable to further sum it by?

Please let me know if you need more information or have questions.

Thanks,
Raoul

Comment: did you forget to paste the `Dummy1` data frame?

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick solution using `data.table` package:

Step1: Create the `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(
  BillN=c('B1','B1','B1','B1','B2','B2','B2','B2','B3','B3','B3','B3'),
  Item_Name=c('Prod A','Prod B','Prod C','Prod D','Prod A','Prod B','Prod C','Prod D','Prod A','Prod B','Prod C','Prod D'), # going on to Product(n)
  Quantity=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1)
)
```

Step2: Set appropriate key:

```
setkey(DT,BillN)
```

Step3: Make sure that the string vector `Item_Name` is not a `factor`.

```
DT[,Item_Name := as.character(Item_Name)]
```

Step4: Perform the operation by `key`

```
DT[,list(Item_Name =paste(Item_Name,collapse=" + "),
         Quantity=sum(Quantity)),
   by=key(DT)]
```

You can use the result as it is, or collapse each row! Which is simple!!

Comment: This worked perfectly for me! And on my entire dataset of over a hundred thousand records! Absolutely brilliant! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Glad to hear that!! I realized that you have not accepted the answer yet... Were you looking for anything more??

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example summing both the `Quantity` variables by `BillN` and the count of `BillN`s as your expected output wants:

```
Dummy1 <- data.frame(BillN, Item_Name, Quantity)

ldply(by(Dummy1, Dummy1$BillN, simplify=TRUE, FUN=function(x) {

  BillN <- x[1,]$BillN
  Quantity <- sum(x$Quantity)
  Item_Name <- paste(as.character(unique(x$Item_Name)), sep="", collapse=" + ")
  BillCt <- nrow(x)

  return(data.frame(BillN, Item_Name, Quantity, BillCt))

}))[2:5]

##  BillN                         Item_Name Quantity BillCt
## 1    B1 Prod A + Prod B + Prod C + Prod D        6      4
## 2    B2 Prod A + Prod B + Prod C + Prod D        5      4
## 3    B3 Prod A + Prod B + Prod C + Prod D        5      4
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, this works brilliantly. Let me scale this to the main dataset. Will let you know if I hit a wall. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi, This worked well, but on a limited dataset of around 200 observations. Beyond that, it took almost 3 hours for a dataset of around 103,000 records and ultimately hung my PC. I increased the memory allocation to R and ran it on a limited dataset of around 3000 records but the same happened. Is there a workaround to make it  effective for large datasets please?